# Overview of WPF controls

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, themes, styling

I am testing to style the wpf 4.0 controls in my application and can see how some controls contains others. For example is the Label control containing a TextBox control.
Have you seen any good overview of how the different controls inherit each other to easier understand the impact on other controls when styling one control?

/SP

Answer (score 0):

You can use Expression Blend or some [other tools](http://neilmosafi.blogspot.com/2007/04/new-tool-for-viewing-wpf-default.html) to view the default control templates.